# Exposing Code Signing information in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-signing

I own a public and open-source Windows Forms/C# application in a Github repo that I want to start code signing with my certificate through Azure Pipelines CI.  I have set up my pipeline and it is building fine, the next step is to integrate automatic code signing, which until this point I have been doing manually. I have taken the following steps:

- Certificate has been added to Secure File storage
- Code Signing Extension Installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stefankert.codesigning
- Task variables have been created and marked as secret

After adding a task, the YML generating is:

`- task: codesigning@2
  inputs:
    secureFileId: '$(certName)'
    signCertPassword: '$(certPass)'
    files: '**/*.exe'
    timeServer: 'http://timestamp.digicert.com'
    hashingAlgorithm: 'SHA256'`

So, saving this, it is obviously going to update my **azure-pipelines.yml** in my repository. Is it possible to perform code signing in Azure Pipelines without exposing any information in the repository?  Is this considered best practice for code-signing in Azure Pipelines?

Comment: If you use a secure file storage and use secret variables (preferably from a variable group in your "Library") then there shouldn't be any information exposed to the Repository

Comment: If you want to get rid of the whole task then i'd move the code-signing into a release-pipeline so that your code will be signed on releasing to whatever your target is

Comment: @D.J. Thanks.  I assumed the only visible information in my repo would be the build steps in **repository/azure-pipelines.yml**, which would contain the signing-code above with variables -- There may be no harm in showing that but maybe I should look into your recommendation to sign through a release pipeline instead.